# php Regex file path | second matching after specific character

Tags: php, regex

I trying to extract file patches, without disk letter, that are inside text. Like from `AvastSecureBrowserElevationService; C:\Program Files (x86)\AVAST Software\Browser\Application\elevation_service.exe [X]` extract `:\Program Files (x86)\AVAST Software\Browser\Application\elevation_service.exe`.

My actual regex look like this, but it will stop on any space, which can contains file names.

```
(?<=:\\)([^ ]*)
```

The soulution that I figure out is, that I can match first space character after dot, because there is very little chance that there will be some directory name with space after dot, and I will always do fast manual check. But I do not know how to write this in regex

Comment: There are dots in `73.0.1270.86`

Comment: @anubhava But after this dots are not any space character and how I wrote, there is always space for fast manual recheck. I remove it for better understand

Comment: ok you can use: `(?<=[a-zA-Z]):[^.]*\.\S+`

Comment: @anubhava it looks that it will work, write it as answer so I will can flag it as right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for this purpose:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z]):[^.]+\.\S+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JkeZ5K/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=[a-zA-Z])`: Lookbehind to assert we have a English letter before `:`
- `:`: Match literal `:`
- `[^.]+`: Match 1+ non-dot characters
- `\.`: Match literal `.`
- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters

Answer (score 1):

Here we would consume our entire string, as we collect what we wish to output, and we would `preg_replace`:

```
.+C(:\\.+\..+?)\s.+
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/.+C(:\\.+\..+?)\s.+/m';
$str = 'AvastSecureBrowserElevationService; C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AVAST Software\\Browser\\Application\\elevation_service.exe [X]';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IL24Uz/1/)

Comment: The files can have all sorts of ending like .dll, .php etc and also there can be drivers letter like D, F etc. The @anubhava soulution looks that it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
[A-Z]\K:.+\.\w+
```

It will match any capital letter followed by `:`, then any character string ending wit `.`, followed by at least one word character.

`\K` removes from the match what comes before it.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nDQvcU/2)